# c#: shorter way to write v1! ? v2 : !v2

Tags: c#, syntax, boolean

Can I write

```
bool v1, v2;
// ...
```

EDIT: I am very sorry for the confusions. The correct statement should be:

```
bool v3 = !v1 ? v2 : !v2;
```

ORIGINAL I asked for

```
bool v3 = v1 ? v2 : !v2;
```

even shorter? Or: Is there an operator which will have the same result?

So I marked Anders Abels answer as correct, because he answered my initial question. I only need to invert his answer.

Comment: Could you provide entire statement not only condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xor` (the `^` operator) which will give `true` if one and only one of the operands is `true`. It will return the opposite of what you want, so you have to negate everything:

```
!(v1 ^ v2);
```

Comment: I think it's interesting to note that *xor* is the same as *not equal*. So your expression is the same as `v1 == v2`.

Answer (score 11):

I think `v1==v2` should do it.

Edit:

For the updated question, it's `v1!=v2`, or `v1^v2` as Anders said.

Comment: Simple and elegant. I rest my case :-)

Comment: I think `v1 != v2` is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Vlad already provided the correct answer. I'm just adding a simple table that might help showing how these kind of problems could be solved.

```
           | v2 = true  | v2 = false |
-----------+------------+------------+
v1 = true  |   false    |    true    |
-----------+------------+------------+
v1 = false |    true    |   false    |
-----------+------------+------------+
```

Edit: The table has been updated to match the updated question.

As Vlad has already metioned the expression can be refactored into `!=`. Parantheses added for clarification. They are not needed by the compiler.

```
bool v3 = (v1 != v2);
```

Comment: My mistake. I didn't write correct question... His answer is marked now. Thank you for the table.